# Bootstrap Carousel Arrows... How To Vertical Center?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm having problems with the Bootstrap Carousel. It appears the right hand arrow is higher than the left.

I haven't used Bootstrap much but I'm sure this has happened before.

Bare in mind I have applied absolutely none of my own styles.

check the image below to see what I mean.

http://s30.postimg.org/g83v874tt/Screen_Shot_2015_10_25_at_17_24_47.png&#13;

Thanks Joe

Comment: you should bear in mind it is easy to ask than checking yourself http://i.imgur.com/O8HBhkl.png :) Nothing wrong, optical illusion or just tiredness

Comment: That line doesn't look straight to me haha! Maybe it's just my eyes :)

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)